# What does "FDProxy.Open error 2" mean when accessing CloudSQL from Go App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

We sometimes get the error "FDProxy.Open error 2" back from CloudSQL when attempting to execute a query.  I think that this means "connection refused because there are already too many open connections" but I'd love some official confirmation of this as I'm not positive.  I'm also not sure if it always means this or if there are also other error states (e.g. write QPS too high) that will also trigger this error.  If it matters, we are using the Go-MySQL-Driver although we have also seen it when using the mymysql driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We currently have a limit of 30 Cloud SQL connections per App Engine app instance (see the Warning from [1]) but that restriction can sometimes be applied to a total number of connections from a subset of those. This will be fixed in the App Engine 1.9.5 release when a strict per App Engine instance limiting will be rolled out. Sorry for the pain. :-(

[1] https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/#Java_Connect_to_your_database

Comment: When you say appserver, do you mean a cloudsql appserver?  Or an app engine instance?  Is this connection limit (of 30) independent of the CloudSQL instance size that I use?  Or would upgrading my instance size to gain more a higher concurrent connection limit help?  Lastly can you clarify what "per instance limiting" means?  What will the precise limits be after that?  thanks!

Comment: I'm a little hazy on the terminology here -- does "appserver" refer to a physical instance on which multiple FE instance VMs are running? And if so, does that mean that the 30-connection limit is implemented by the CloudSQL instance, e.g., by incoming IP?

Comment: I update the response to make it clearer. The new limits will be per App Engine instance and it will be sufficient to allow using one Cloud SQL connection for each HTTP request for regular App Engine instances.

Comment: Razvan, I see that App Engine 1.9.5 was released on May 20 but I don't see anything in the release notes related to the connection limit you mention above.  Was this rolled on with 1.9.5 as was originally scheduled?

Comment: Yes, the feature was rolled in 1.9.5.

Comment: We are still seeing some "Cloud SQL connection error 2" errors (I'm guessing this is the same error just with a new stringification?).  Just from skimming our logs they appear to happen to several different requests all at roughly the same time (i.e. they are bursty).  Does this just mean that we are exceeding the max concurrent connections for our CloudSQL instance?  Obviously I can't say for sure but our back of the envelope math suggests this shouldn't be happening very often.

Comment: Estimates:
We are running a D4 (400 max connections) and the requests that account for most of our cloudsql operations happen ~10x/sec with an average latency of 400ms.  So that would imply an average of 4 concurrent connections.  So my estimates could be off by 2 orders of magnitude before we would actually start hitting our connection limit at all, which seems unlikely...

Comment: Quick question: do you set the max_concurrent_requests to something explicitly? The max number of connections we allow is 12 so that needs to be at most that. 

Also: if you send an email to cloud-sql@google.com with the name of the App Engine app and the Cloud SQL instance I can dig some deeper on what is going on.